# Current day's counts vs Yesterday's counts difference into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

The main "issue": I am inserting the current day's row counts from every table into a table. The main goal is to have a table which has the current day's vs yesterday's counts difference for each day.
What is essential that to know that the current days row total is or not than the yesterday's total.

Example :

```
+----------+-------------+--------+
|  Table   |    Date     | Count  |
+----------+-------------+--------+
| Table 1  | 2020-01-01  |     50 |
| Table 1  | 2020-01-02  |    150 |
| Table 1  | 2020-01-03  |    565 |
+----------+-------------+--------+
```

and this is what I would like to have as a final product:

```
+----------+-------------+--------------------+
|  Table   |    Date     | Count (difference) |
+----------+-------------+--------------------+
| Table 1  | 2020-01-01  |                 50 |
| Table 1  | 2020-01-02  |                100 |
| Table 1  | 2020-01-03  |                415 |
+----------+-------------+--------------------+
```

I was thinking in a kind of solution which is similar to the Rolling Forecast, but after a while I stuck and still thinking that what can be the best approach for this.

This is the current state of my "code":

```
DECLARE @SQL_RecordCounting nvarchar(MAX) = 

(
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(CAST( N'SELECT N' AS nvarchar(MAX)) +QUOTENAME(name,'''') +N' AS [DatabaseName],  -- Database
    T.NAME AS [TableName], -- Table 
    0-P.ROWS AS [RowCount], -- Counting the rows
    GETDATE() as [Datetime] -- To have a history 
FROM ' +
    QUOTENAME(name) +
    N'.sys.tables T
LEFT JOIN ' +
    QUOTENAME(name) +
    N'.sys.partitions P ON T.object_id = P.OBJECT_ID 
WHERE T.is_ms_shipped = 0 -- excluding the MS provided tables 
AND P.rows <> 0 -- only the zeros
GROUP BY T.Name,
         P.Rows'
         , NCHAR(10) + N' UNION ALL ' + NCHAR(10)
) + NCHAR(10) + N'ORDER BY Name;'
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id > 4  -- excluding the sys dbs  
AND name not in ('DELTA','work','stage_dev') -- dbs which are out of scope
)
;

--INSERT INTO [ABC].[dbo].[TablesRecords]
exec sys.sp_executesql  @SQL_RecordCounting
```

Comment: The fact you want to check get row counts on a daily basis really smells of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) If I am honest.

Comment: No problem(yes, it can looks like and XY problem, but don't know how to approach this thing in an efficient way), actually I don't know what is the best approach of this, I can insert the data into multiple tables and after that I can calculate it from them, but it seems too rigid and not elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep the totals in your table `TablesRecords` and query it using:

```
select tr.*,
       (tr.count - lag(tr.count, 1, 0) over (partition by tr.table order by tr.date)) as count_difference
from [ABC].[dbo].[TablesRecords] tr;
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid to using the TableRecords as an individual source, but in the end I realized that it is better to have an individual table and I can use it for other purposes too.

Answer (score 3):

Use :

```
COALESCE([Count] - LAG([Count]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]), [Count])
```

In the select clause of your query.

Comment: I am using that select to populate the data for each day as you can see that I am using a simple getdate() (it will run once a day) to have the dates or should I have a separate level to execute the COALESCE([Count] - LAG([Count]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]), [Count])?

Comment: @mpataki Don't populate another column, just create an index on (Date, Count)